# In unit testing, how to compare two objects without using operator== which may miss new members?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, comparison-operators

In unit testing code, which is the best way to test the `operator==` comparison operator in the hypothesis that new members may have been added to the class?

E.g.:

```
struct A {
   int a, b;
   bool operator==( const A& other ) const { return( a == other.a && b == other.b ); }
};

int Test() {
   A a1, a2;
   EXPECT_TRUE( a1 == a2 );
}
```

then we change A, adding a new member variable `c`.
With the current test/comparison operator, we will get false negatives when `c` differs.

Is there an alternative/low level way to compare two objects?

Comment: Perhaps you can assert about the size of the object. If the size differ from the one for which you have wrote your operator==, you know that something change in your object, just an idea.

Comment: For a class like you show, why would you ever implement `operator==` yourself? Let the compiler do it, it won't miss any members.

Comment: Test the reverse: Check that comparison of two objects that _differ_ (by e.g. the last member) returns `false`. (Of course you should also test that equal objects compare equal at some point, in case someone implemented `operator==` as `return false;`).

Comment: @JesperJuhl - That is a simplified example.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Could you please expand your answer?

Comment: In C++ 20, you will be able to `bool operator==(const A&) = default;`

Comment: There is only one proper way - update unit tests accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

When testing your `operator==`, you should check two things:

1. It returns `true` when the objects are equal.
2. It returns `false` when the objects are inequal.

As you correctly observed, criterion 1 will be unaffected when someone adds more members but forgets to update the `operator==` definition. That's why the second criterion is important. Notice that right now, your test would pass by implementing `operator==` as `return true;`.

So, you might want your tests shaped like this:

```
int Test() {
   A a12{1, 2};
   A a12_{1, 2};
   A a23{2, 3};
   EXPECT_TRUE( a12 == a12 );
   EXPECT_TRUE( a12 == a12_ );
   EXPECT_FALSE( a12 == a23 );
   EXPECT_FALSE( a23 == a12 );
}
```

Now, given this code, someone who adds member `c` might also forget to update the tests and nothing would fail (note: If `A` had a constructor instead of being an aggregate, the test would fail to build and this would be a non-issue, but the question contains an aggregate). There is a certain level of incompetence you can't guard against. Also note that maybe you *don't* want `c` to contribute to comparisons (what if it's e.g. a `std::mutex`?) - it depends on your definition of (in)equality.

Overall, don't try to predict the future, it is usually wasted effort and won't work (even though you will mainly remember the times it worked out).

Comment: Yes, there are cases where you want to ignore some members from the comparison, but most of the times what you need is a straightforward comparison of all the member variables. That is what I am looking for...